# USA to Canada emigration and income tax

Tags: united-states, canada, income-tax, international

From January to August 2010 I worked in the USA and then I moved to Canada where I'm a student.  Do I file an income tax return in Canada, USA or both?  (If Canada, how do I get all of the deductions that I paid in the US back?)

Also, I bought stocks in March of 2010 and made some unrealized capital again.  How do I minimize the capital gains tax I eventually pay on those stocks?  Can I sell them in March, pay $0 capital gains tax next year (having held them for one year) and rebuy the same stocks in Canada?

Comment: Are you a US citizen or greencard holder?

Comment: No, I'm Canadian.  I was on TN visas for 3 years.

Comment: OK - the reason I asked was that as a US citizen (and to a certain extent as a GC holder), you'd have to file a tax return on your worldwide with the IRS even if you're not living in the US. Can't help past that.

Comment: @Timo, yes, thanks, I'm aware of that requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer this from the Canadian perspective. I would suggest that you consider filing a tax return in Canada since you are a Canadian citizen and if you're now a student, you can likely claim or carry forward tuition and education amounts. With respect to your foreign income, you would declare it on [line 104](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/lns101-170/104/frgn-eng.html). Foreign tax withheld may be claimed on [line 405](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns409-485/405-eng.html) using [form T2209](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t2209/README.html). Canada and the US have a tax treaty and I have used the T2209 in the past to deduct foreign dividend tax withheld from US investments.

As for the US return, if they have similar residency conditions, I don't see why you wouldn't need to fill it out. I can't help you with that or your capital gains question.

Comment: @Neil: Out of curiosity, I've read some more about filing taxes for US-Canada taxes in the past few hours. The final thing I would suggest is going to an accountant that has experience with both tax systems and optimizing your tax situation by taking advantage of each country's residency requirements.